# Distribution of tees among students

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a certain problem, I am asked to find how many possible distributions are of $2n$ tees of $n$ colours ($2$ identical tees per colour) to $2n$ distinct students. I see that it is simple, but I want to assure my answer.

Since students are clearly distinguishable and the number of tees is the same as of students, this would be a permutation of $2n$ elements, in which there are $2$ identical elements of $n$ types. This is, the number is $\frac{2n!}{2^n}$.

Another way to think about it is to say there is a list of length $2n$, and for the first colour one has to choose $2$ positions: ${2n \choose 2}$, for the second one ${2n-2 \choose 2}$, and for the $i$-colour in general, ${2n-2\cdot(i-1)\choose 2}, i \in \{1 \dots n\}$. The result is the product of each combinatoric number, which gives the same result as above if I'm not wrong. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I would warn you to use $(2n)!$ rather than $2n!$ to help distinguish it from $2(n!)$

Comment: You are right, I'll consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the correct answer and procedure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is against our policy to answer a solution-verification question with a simple “Yes, that is correct”.